# Rails: Create Model and join table at the same time, has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have three Models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :factor_questions
  has_many :bigfivefactors, through: :factor_questions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :factor_questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bigfivefactors
end

class Bigfivefactor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :factor_questions
  has_many :questions, through: :factor_questions
end
```

and my join-table, which holds not only the `bigfivefactor_id` and `question_id` but another integer-colum `value`.

```
class FactorQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bigfivefactor
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Creating an new `Question` works fine, using in my `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :questiontext %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :questiontext %>
  </div>

<%= f.collection_check_boxes :bigfivefactor_ids, Bigfivefactor.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
  <p><%= cb.check_box + cb.text %></p>
<% end %>
```

This let's me check or uncheck as many `bigfivefactors` as i want.

But, as i mentioned before, the join model also holds a `value`.

**Question:**

How can I add a text-field next to each check-box to add/edit the 'value' on the fly?

[For better understanding, i added an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUJn0.png)

In the console, i was able to basically do this:

```
q= Question.create(questiontext: "A new Question")
b5 = Bigfivefactor.create(name: "Neuroticism")
q.bigfivefactors << FactorQuestion.create(question: q, bigfivefactor: b5, value: 10)
```

I also found out to edit my `questions_controller`:

```
def new
  @question = Question.new
  @question.factor_questions.build
end
```

**But i have no idea how to put that into my view.**

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Big Five Factors model considerations

It looks like your Bigfivefactors are not supposed to be modified with each update to question.  I'm actually assuming these will be CMS controlled fields (such that an admin defines them).  If that is the case, remove the accepts_nested_attributes for the bigfivefactors in the questions model.  This is going to allow param injection that will change the behavior sitewide.  You want to be able to link to the existing bigfivefactors, so `@question.factor_questions.first.bigfivefactor.name` is the label and `@question.factor_questions.first.value` is the value.  Notice, these exist on different 'planes' of the object model, so there wont be much magic we can do here.

### Parameters

In order to pass the nested attributes that you are looking for the paramater needs to look like this:

```
params = { 
 question: { 
   questiontext: "What is the average air speed velocity of a sparrow?", 
   factor_questions_attributes: [ 
     { bigfivefactor_id: 1, value: 10 }, 
     { bigfivefactor_id: 2, value: 5  } ]
    } 
  }
```

Once we have paramaters that look like that, running `Question.create(params[:question])` will create the Question and the associated `@question.factor_questions`.  In order to create paramaters like that, we need html form checkbox element with a name "question[factor_questions_attributes][0][bigfivefactor_id]" and a value of "1", then a text box with a name of "question[factor_question_attributes][0][value]"

[Api: nested_attributes_for has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-One-to-many)

### View

Here's a stab at the view you need using fields_for to build the nested attributes through the fields for helper.

```
<%= f.fields_for :factor_questions do |factors| %>
  <%= factors.collection_check_boxes( :bigfivefactor_id, Bigfivefactor.all, :id, :name) do |cb| %>
    <p><%= cb.check_box + cb.text %><%= factors.text_field :value %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

[API: fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

I'm not sure exactly how it all comes together in the view.  You may not be able to use the built in helpers.  You may need to create your own collection helper.  `@question.factor_questions`.  Like:

```
<%= f.fields_for :factor_questions do |factors| %>
  <%= factors.check_box :_destroy, {checked => factors.object.persisted?}, '0','1' %> # display all existing checked boxes in form
  <%= factors.label :_destroy, factors.object.bigfivefactor.name %>
  <%= factors.text_box :value %>
  <%= (Bigfivefactor.all - @question.bigfivefactors).each do |bff| %>
    <%= factors.check_box bff.id + bff.name %><%= factors.text_field :value %></p> # add check boxes that aren't currently checked
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I honestly know that this isn't functional as is.  I hope the insight about the paramters help, but without access to an actual rails console, I doubt I can create code that accomplishes what you are looking for.  Here's a helpful link: [Site point does Complex nested queries](http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/#more-complicated-relationships)

Comment: Happy new year! While your post did not work out of the box, i could figure  out how to do this, thanks. Will update this question as soon as possible with my solution.

Comment: I'm actually trying to achieve the exact same thing this question is asking. Just never was able to phrase it correctly! Whats more I keep wondering to myself what is the Rails "convention" of doing this? It has me pulling my hair out! One minute I think it makes sense to build the association record in the controller - and it doesn't feel right to be calling X.all in my view. I didn't think removing accepts_nested_attributes was needed - I will try playing around with that now. I'm just trying to learn rails & it seems like I'm picking through a graveyard as every question is from early 00's!